# Array defining and exporting to file

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code, which is supposed t first check if the current registry has EST or CST as a TIME ZONE value, and then also adds to the pool every registry with CA as STATE value, but for some reason it only exports the EST and CST registrys but not the CA registry. What am I doing wrong here?

```
df=df[df['TIME ZONE'].isin(['EST','CST'])]
df=shuffle(df)
df=df[~df['STATE'].isin(['CA'])]
CC= df['CollNum'].tolist()
CC = list(dict.fromkeys(CC))

for COLL in CC: 
    dfmod=df[df['CollNum']==COLL]
    spreadSheetName=r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\EAST CST '+str(COLL)+'.csv'
    dfmod.to_csv(spreadSheetName)
```

Comment: It looks like you are filtering out from the dataframe all rows where STATE==CA on the third row of your code. I also can't see where the adding to the pool every registry with CA state is happening. Could you provide a few rows of sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to include data with the label `CA`. Therefore, You should replace this:

```
df=df[~df['STATE'].isin(['CA'])]
```

to this:

```
df=df[df['STATE'].isin(['CA'])]
```

A toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME ZONE':['EST','CST','UAT','UCT'],
                   'STATE':['CA','CA','GC','GC'],
                   'CollNum':[1,2,3,4]})

df=df[df['TIME ZONE'].isin(['EST','CST'])]
df=df[df['STATE'].isin(['CA'])]
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
  TIME ZONE STATE  CollNum
0       EST    CA        1
1       CST    CA        2
```